# align-content and justify-content for flex isn't working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

`align-content` and `justify-content` seem to do nothing when I run it on Chrome and Firefox.

I'm not sure what's wrong.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  height: 90vh;
}
#header {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
#main {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  background-color: coral;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
#footer {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
  background-color: silver;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 915px) {
  #container {
    flex-flow: column wrap-reverse;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="main">Main</div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? It looks like it's working to me - you just didn't have any content in the `div` tags so you couldn't see the result...

Comment: i just found out that justify-content works when i made flex-grow:0 for child elements but the align-content still does nothing.I expected all the 3 boxes to move to the center

Answer (score 0):

They're doing exactly what you're asking them to do.  What's wrong here is your flex definition.

If you want them to be `200px` each, you shouldn't give it a `flex-grow` value of `1` which you're doing in your shorthand `flex-grow: *1* 0 200px`.

Instead, rewrite the `flex` properties as such:

```
#header {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  ...
}
```

**[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/te1wx3pv/)**

As for why `align-content` isn't working, you only have 1 line of items, so it has nothing to do.

> align-content
>
> This aligns a flex container's lines within when there is extra space in the cross-axis, similar to how justify-content aligns individual items within the main-axis.
>
> Note: this property has no effect when there is only one line of flex items.

From: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

I'm guessing what you want is to center vertically *and* horizontally, in which case you don't want `align-content`, you want `align-items`.

Try replacing `align-content: center` with `align-items: center` to get the vertical centering.

**[JSFiddle example of align-items](https://jsfiddle.net/te1wx3pv/1/)**

Comment: i have done that and justify-content now works but align-content still doesn't

Comment: i've checked the link you shared,thanks. It works with the example there but still doesnt work for my code.what am i missing please?

Comment: @Tejumade I made another update.  I'm assuming you're attempting to vertically center those items, correct?

Comment: i copied the code from `working JSFiddle` which works perfectly there but to my amazement it still didn't place the 3 boxes in the middle like i had expected. it did justify it though. i tried it on both chrome and firefox. could this be some sort of bug?

Comment: I would need to see your full code to tell you why.

Comment: i created a gist of it on my github, please check it out. [link](https://gist.github.com/Tejaf/67f64f7d78f5b268397d1a3f89bc981c)

Comment: thanks for your help, `align-items` gives the exact result i was hoping to get. i'm sorry it took a while for me to figure that out :(